# Decorator to allow function to accept arbitrary arguments

Tags: python, decorator

How can I write a decorator so that decorated functions can accept (and ignore) arbitrary arguments?

I have some functions like this:

```
def foo(x):
    return x

def foo2(x, y):
    if bar(y):
        return x
    else:
        return x + 1

def foo3(x, y, z):
    ...
```

`foo()` can calculate the return value for a given `x` just based on `x`, but `foo2()` needs another parameter, and `foo3()` needs a third parameter. I have a method elsewhere that, among other things, calls either `foo()`, `foo2()`, etc depending on a user-specified argument.

Right now, the method just grabs the appropriate function with `getattr(user_arg)` and calls it with all of `x`, `y`, `z`. To avoid a TypeError for the wrong number of arguments, the `foo` functions are all defined with `*args` like this:

```
def foo(x, *args):
    return x
```

But I'd like to just have a decorator to avoid including `*args` in every single `foo` function definition. Is there a way to do that? Or can you suggest a better way to organize this code?

One way would be to write the method like this:

```
if user_arg == 'foo':
    foo(x)
elif user_arg == 'foo2':
    foo2(x, y)
elif user_arg == 'foo3':
    foo3(x, y, z)
```

But I'd really like to avoid this, because there are a lot of `foo` functions, and because I'd like to make it possible to add new `foo` functions without also having to add another branch to the method.

**Edit**: To clarify, it's not the case that I need to call a different `foo` function *based on* the number of arguments. It's arbitrary (user-specified) which of the `foo` functions is called.

```
def foo3(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

def foo4(x, y, z):
    return x + y - z
```

Comment: The pattern that you're describing (dispatching by the number of arguments) has nothing to do with decorators.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How would `@somedecorator def foo(x)` be simpler than `def foo(x, *args)`?

Comment: I'm decorating the functions anyway, so I was hoping to put all of the "make this a `foo`-family function" into one block of code, but maybe the way it's done already is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to determine what arguments the decorated function takes:

```
import functools
import inspect

def ignore_extra_arguments(func):
    args, varargs, kwvarargs, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*wrapper_args, **wrapper_kwargs):
        if varargs is None:
            # remove extra positional arguments
            wrapper_args = wrapper_args[:len(args)]
        if kwvarargs is None:
            # remove extra keyword arguments
            wrapper_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in wrapper_kwargs.iteritems() if k in args}
        return func(*wrapper_args, **wrapper_kwargs)
    return wrapper_func
```

This can be optimized a little by lifting the `if` checks out of `wrapper_func`, at the expense of writing more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named arguments](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) and always call `foo()` (the first function) in order to dispatch to the "right" function, as follows:

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if b:
        return foo2(a, b, c, d)
    else:
        # do your thing

def foo2(a, b, c=None, d=None):        
    if c:
        return foo3(a, b, c, d)
    else:
        # do your thing

def foo3(a, b, c, d=None):                
    ...
```

---

Another option:

```
def foo(a, *b):
    if b:
        return foo2(a, *b)
    else:
        print "in foo"
        # do your thing

def foo2(a, b, *c):       
    if c:
        return foo3(a, b, *c)
    else:
        print "in foo2"
        # do your thing

def foo3(a, b, c, *d):
    print "in foo3"


foo(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good thought - but it won't work for me because some of the `foo` functions take the same set of arguments, but do different things with them. I didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: @user2034412 By setting default value of `None` you can set `foo()` to accept as many arguments as you want - so it sounds like it should work. That said, please checkout the 2nd approach - it's a bit more concise and much more "pythonic"